# Vuetify Styles not visible

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I am a beginner in the world of Vue, so please bear with my foolish question(s).
I have a boilerplate code for a Vue project which I cloned from:
[Vue Enterprise Boilerplate](https://github.com/chrisvfritz/vue-enterprise-boilerplate)

I wanted to use Vuetify components, so I followed the following steps:
1. Cloned the vue-enterprise-boilerplate
2. npm install vuetify --save
3. In my main.js I added the vuetify dependency like:

```
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css';

Vue.use(Vuetify);
```

4. I am using Vue CLI 3 (which comes with the boilerplate), also I have installed the CCS Loader.
5. Now in my app.vue, I have a simple button like:

```
<v-app>
  <v-btn color="primary">Test</v-btn>
</v-app>
```

But when I run the app, I only see the outline of the button, but the styles are missing. Here is a screenshot below:

[image: The 'Test' button, with 'Test' text faintly visible.]

Also here is the dev-tools snapshot:

[image: Dev-Tools Snapshot]

As you can see, the vuetify.min.css is being referenced, I am unable to debug why this is not behaving as per the Vuetify guides.

What steps am I missing?

Comment: What styles missed? In your inspector all is fine, all styles that should be there is there

Comment: @Aldarund I have mentioned color="primary", which is a blue color in Vuetify, that is missing...

Comment: @pk10 did you find a solution for this problem? I'm experiencing the same issue

Comment: try to replace `v-app` with `div` as a wrapper and use it under `template` tag.

Answer (score 8):

What fixed the issue for me was the adding of class `.v-application` at the top most html tag (or the first one after `template` tag). Usually if I add `<v-app>` it all works but for some reason using vuitify 2.0.4 this didn't worked (may be because I'm not using vue-cli and webpack but parcel.js).

So adding this class solved the same issue for me.

**EDIT**

Actually I just found why `v-app` was ignored. Since I'm using vuetify 2.0.4. without vue-cli and webpack I need to include the vuetify components by my self like so:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify, {
    VCard,
    VImg,
    VCardTitle,
    VBtn,
    VCardActions,
    VCardText,
    VProgressCircular,
    VSpacer,
    VDialog,
    VDivider,
    VAlert,
    VApp,
} from 'vuetify/lib'

Vue.use(Vuetify, {
    components: {
        VCard,
        VImg,
        VCardTitle,
        VBtn,
        VCardActions,
        VCardText,
        VProgressCircular,
        VSpacer,
        VDialog,
        VDivider,
        VAlert,
        VApp,
    },
})

import 'material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css';

export default new Vuetify({})
```

Which is then imported in the vue app like this:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import vuetify from './src/vuetify'

import VocabularyApp from "./src/App.vue";

new Vue({
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(VocabularyApp)
}).$mount('#app-tutor');
```

So v-app wasn't working as I didn't included it in the list of components that I need for my app to work. More you can find [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start).

Comment: V-App is needed in order for any styles to be applied. Adding this worked for me.

Comment: Oh man! you saved me after 6 hours searching! yeah, the `v-app` component is essentially needed to make all styles visible. But, in my case integrating with `Laravel-Mix`.

Comment: My app is wrapped inside V-App too but still not getting the css, has this been solved yet?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the vuetiful world of vue.

You are looking into the shadow dom, please inspect the button element not the div element inside button element. The parent button element of the div will have classes like .primary .error based on the prop you give.

See the screenshot:

[image: vuetify button inspected]

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I used stylus and had the `css.requireModuleExtension = false` option in vue.config.js. Styles just didn't load. Switching it to the `true` or removing this option did the trick.

```
// vue.congif.js

module.exports = {
  // ...
  css: {
    // ...
    requireModuleExtension: true
  }
  // ...
}
```